# Axlsx gem, adding style changes the format of the cell

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, axlsx

I'm using the axlsx gem in order to produce excel reports from my rails application. I do however run into some problems when applying a custom style to a cell that includes a date.

The style that I'm applying looks like this:

```
pink = s.add_style fg_color: '000000', bg_color: 'FF99CC'
```

Before applying the style the cell value is "2015-02-02" and has a format of date which is what I want. After applying the style the value however changes into "42400" in a general format.

Is it possible to change the background color without effecting the value in the cell or keeping its format?